# Find out the size of a .tar.gz archive in the terminal without unpacking

Tags: terminal, gzip, archiving, tar

I have a 32GB .tar.gz archive and I'd like to know the size of the files if I unpack this compressed archive. I'd like to avoid unpacking the archive first and than use e.g. `du`.

Is it also possible to **find out the size of the contained files without unpacking the compressed archive** (on a Linux and/or MacOSX system)?

For another archive I know, that it also contains .tar.gz files. Is it also possible to calculate the size of the unpacked archives that are contained within an archive? (for example by setting a level to which the "unpacking" should be simulated?)

Comment: What kind of system/terminal/command processor? Linux, Windows, ... (bash, ...)?

Comment: I'm using the bash on Linux and MacOSX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Just use `-tv` to list the contents with their sizes.  E.g.

```
% tar -tvzf sometools2.tar.gz 
-rw-r--r-- madler/admin   3442 2005-02-27 21:40 pngdat.c
-rw-r--r-- madler/admin  24938 2005-02-27 21:39 infgen.c
```

If you want to add up the sizes (like `du`), you can use `awk`:

```
% tar -tvzf sometools2.tar.gz|awk '{ s += $3 } END { print s }'
28380
```

For an imbedded `.tar.gz` file, you would need to do those individually when you find them by sending them to `stdout` with `-O`:

```
% tar -tvzf imbed.tar.gz 
-rw-r--r-- madler/staff    505 2012-02-12 00:06 lucas.c
-rw-r--r-- madler/staff  27913 2005-03-20 11:10 lzwtry.c
-rw-r--r-- madler/staff   8314 2005-02-27 21:42 sometools2.tar.gz
% tar -xOzf imbed.tar.gz sometools2.tar.gz | tar -tvzf - | awk '{ s += $3 } END { print s }'
28380
```

You can write a script to find those in the `-tv` output and then extract them, and even do it recursively.  I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Note, these options are for GNU tar, which is what is on both Linux and Mac OS X.  The options for BSD tar may be different.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that the `.tar.gz` suffix means it's a compressed `tar` file. `tar` is just a means of packing multiple files and directories into one file. It does not have any compression by default. This is where `gzip` comes in. It's a tool for compressing a single file. Hence the aforementioned suffix means it's a compressed bundle of files and/or directories.

### If you want to see the compression rates for each file in a zipped tar bundle, see the [answer by Mark Adler](https://superuser.com/a/521598/632239).

If you are only interested in the whole zipped file (or bundle), the correct way of determining the unpacked size is:

```
gunzip -l ${file}
```

Example output:

```
$ gunzip -l syslog.1.gz
     compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
        4465670            33295551  86.6% syslog.1
```

The compressed and uncompressed numbers show bytes. Ergo my syslog.1 file would be about 32 MB uncompressed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do something like this on the terminal (AFAIK it is not possible). But most programming libs for extracting archives also allow to query content information (e.g. tree, size of content) without extracting the whole compressed contents.

So you could create a command line tool with any programming language that will fit your needs and then call it from the command line.